# Making columns responsive in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've written a basic code like this for experimental purposes:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            .pos {
                position: relative;
            }
            .well1, .well2 {
                position: relative;
                height: 380px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container pos">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="well"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="well well1"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="well well2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="well"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the output:
[image: img]
But the same layout doesn't appear in mobile screens.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Change your `col-sm-*` classes to `col-xs-*`. Your mobile device is using the xs breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap,the col-xx-x classes are relative to specifics media queries. So here, you'll have to had the class col-xs-6 if you want your 50% column to stay 50% when you are below 767px. Your markup should look like this :

```
<body>
    <div class="container pos">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="well"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <div class="well well1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <div class="well well2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="well"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```